# Perl debugger various outputs

Tags: perl, debugging

While writing script I noticed some very strange Perl behavior. The task is to trim last character of string stored in `$temp1` variable, this can be done using either `chop($temp1)` or more complicated `substr($temp1, 0, length($temp1) - 1)`. These both work as one-liners but in my script the `substr` solution does not work. Below is example from debugger:

## 1st PROBLEM:

## 1st SOLUTION - NOT WORKING:

```
main::(delmid_n.pl:24):     if (($state == 0) && ($_ !~ $musr) && ($_ !~ $lusr)) {
>> n
main::(delmid_n.pl:54):         $strprn=substr($temp1, 0, length($temp1) - 1);
>> p $temp1
                (-,user2,t-mobile.co.uk)\

>> p substr($temp1, 0, length($temp1) - 1) . "\n";
                (-,user2,t-mobile.co.uk)


  DB<4> 
main::(delmid_n.pl:55):     print $strprn . "\n";
  DB<4> 


main::(delmid_n.pl:56):         $temp1 = "";
  DB<4>
```

As you can see in the `$strprn` variable, nothing is stored. If the same piece of code (which is stored into the `$strprn` variable) is printed via the 'p' command, the output is OK. This "bug" can be overcome using the mentioned `chop()` function (see code below):

## 2nd SOLUTION - WORKING:

```
main::(delmid_w.pl:24):     if (($state == 0) && ($_ !~ $musr) && ($_ !~ $lusr)) {
>> p $temp1
                (-,user2,t-mobile.co.uk)\

  DB<4> n
main::(delmid_w.pl:56):     chop ($temp1);
  DB<4> n
main::(delmid_w.pl:57):     print $temp1;
  DB<4> n
                (-,user2,t-mobile.co.uk)
main::(delmid_w.pl:58):         $temp1 = "";
  DB<4>
```

The above code is exactly the same as the first example, but the following two lines are from 1st example:

```
$strprn=substr($temp1, 0, length($temp1) - 1);
print $strprn . "\n";
```

are replaced with following two lines in the 2nd example:

```
chop ($temp1);
print $temp1;
```

What is wrong with the 2nd solution?

## 2nd PROBLEM:

This is a problem which I do not have a workaround for, so far.

```
 DB<1> 
main::(delbeg_n.pl:15): $state = 0;
  DB<1> 
main::(delbeg_n.pl:16): $muser = qr/\(-,user1,[^,]+\.co\.uk\)\\$/;
  DB<1> 
main::(delbeg_n.pl:19): line: while (<>) {
  DB<1> 
main::(delbeg_n.pl:20):     chomp;      # strip record separator
  DB<1> 
main::(delbeg_n.pl:21):     @Fld = split(/\s+/, $_,);
  DB<1> 
main::(delbeg_n.pl:23):     if (($state == 0) && ($Fld[1] =~ $muser)) {
  DB<1> p $Fld[1]        
(-,user1,one2one.co.uk)\

  DB<2> n
main::(delbeg_n.pl:43):         print $_;
  DB<2> p $_
netgroup1       (-,user1,one2one.co.uk)\

  DB<3> if ($Fld[1] =~ $muser) {print "TRUE"}
TRUE
```

As you can see after executing line 21 in the code, the next execution line is 43 (the else statement). Why is the following condition not evaluated as a true, allowing the code to continue with line 23, 24, 25?

```
if (($state == 0) && ($Fld[1] =~ $muser))
```

The following line was inserted as a demonstration that the condition should be evaluated as a true:

```
if ($Fld[1] =~ $muser) {print "TRUE"}
```

Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Both problems are related. There is something strange at the end of the line.

First, it looks as if you have a newline character after the slash at the end of the line that you have not chomped off -- at least that is what the debugger shows:

```
>> p $temp1
                (-,user2,t-mobile.co.uk)\

  DB<4> n
```

If there was no newline it would have been

```
>> p $temp1
                (-,user2,t-mobile.co.uk)\
  DB<4> n
```

So, there should be two characters: `\` and newline.

Why the weird behavior -- I don't know without looking at your input file.

Also, instead of using string length, you can just do `substr( $string, 0, -1 )` -- that will also return all but the last character.

That is probably the reason for your second problem -- I guess that `\(-,user1,[^,]+\.co\.uk\)\\` matches and it is the end of line marker `$` that causes the mismatch.

- `use strict` please
- check the file types (dos, unix, old mac)
- view the file in a hex editor

Comment: Thanks for reply I am perl newbie and most code was generated with a2p, the input file looks like this: http://pastebin.com/v540sjpd PS: forgive my ignorance but I did not find reply button on stackoverflow just possibility to comment.

Comment: Found some sources about chomp based on your suggestion, my code starts like this: while (<>) { chomp; blabla } here is full code http://pastebin.com/mRwJESav